# Same MySQL Query Returning Different Results on Same Server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xeround

I am running the following query.  Sometimes it returns around 100 records, as expected, other times is returns only one record with NULL for all of the values of the joined fields.  Also, explain returns a different result almost everytime.

Here is the query:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
`fieldreps`.`user_id` AS `fieldreps.user_id`,
 `fieldreps`.`availability_id` AS `fieldreps.availability_id`,
 `fieldreps`.`applicant_type` AS `fieldreps.applicant_type`,
 `fieldreps`.`license_number` AS `fieldreps.license_number`,
 `fieldreps`.`license_exp` AS `fieldreps.license_exp`,
 `fieldreps`.`license_state` AS `fieldreps.license_state`,
 `fieldreps`.`car` AS `fieldreps.car`,
 `fieldreps`.`authorized_worker` AS `fieldreps.authorized_worker`,
 `fieldreps`.`restrictions` AS `fieldreps.restrictions`,
 `fieldreps`.`night` AS `fieldreps.night`,
 `fieldreps`.`day` AS `fieldreps.day`,
 `fieldreps`.`longer` AS `fieldreps.longer`,
 `fieldreps`.`commitment` AS `fieldreps.commitment`,
 `fieldreps`.`travel_metro` AS `fieldreps.travel_metro`,
 `fieldreps`.`travel_states` AS `fieldreps.travel_states`,
 `fieldreps`.`big_employee` AS `fieldreps.big_employee`,
 `fieldreps`.`employed` AS `fieldreps.employed`,
 `fieldreps`.`retail` AS `fieldreps.retail`,
 `fieldreps`.`status` AS `fieldreps.status`,
 `fieldreps`.`start` AS `fieldreps.start`,
 `fieldreps`.`sales` AS `fieldreps.sales`,
 `fieldreps`.`study` AS `fieldreps.study`,
 `fieldreps`.`relevant` AS `fieldreps.relevant`,
 `fieldreps`.`experience` AS `fieldreps.experience`,
 `fieldreps`.`claims` AS `fieldreps.claims`,
 `fieldreps`.`education` AS `fieldreps.education`,
 `fieldreps`.`degree_details` AS `fieldreps.degree_details`,
 `fieldreps`.`degree_institution` AS `fieldreps.degree_institution`,
 `fieldreps`.`other_training` AS `fieldreps.other_training`,
 `fieldreps`.`jobs` AS `fieldreps.jobs`,
 `fieldreps`.`current_training` AS `fieldreps.current_training`,
 `fieldreps`.`interested` AS `fieldreps.interested`,
 `fieldreps`.`achievements` AS `fieldreps.achievements`,
 `fieldreps`.`passions` AS `fieldreps.passions`,
 `fieldreps`.`ambitions` AS `fieldreps.ambitions`,
 `fieldreps`.`max_travel_time` AS `fieldreps.max_travel_time`,
 `fieldreps`.`creation_time` AS `fieldreps.creation_time`,
 `fieldreps`.`resume` AS `fieldreps.resume`,
 `users`.`user_id` AS `users.user_id`,
 `users`.`email` AS `users.email`,
 `users`.`name` AS `users.name`,
 `users`.`password` AS `users.password`,
 `users`.`given_name` AS `users.given_name`,
 `users`.`title` AS `users.title`,
 `users`.`nationality` AS `users.nationality`,
 `tasks`.`task_id` AS `tasks.task_id`,
 `tasks`.`recurrence_id` AS `tasks.recurrence_id`,
 `tasks`.`parent_id` AS `tasks.parent_id`,
 `tasks`.`user_id` AS `tasks.user_id`,
 `tasks`.`campaign_id` AS `tasks.campaign_id`,
 `tasks`.`location_id` AS `tasks.location_id`,
 `tasks`.`title` AS `tasks.title`,
 `tasks`.`description` AS `tasks.description`,
 `tasks`.`earliest_start` AS `tasks.earliest_start`,
 `tasks`.`deadline` AS `tasks.deadline`,
 `tasks`.`km_estimate` AS `tasks.km_estimate`,
 `tasks`.`estimate` AS `tasks.estimate`,
 `datapoints`.`datapoint_id` AS `datapoints.datapoint_id`,
 `datapoints`.`task_id` AS `datapoints.task_id`,
 `datapoints`.`datatype_id` AS `datapoints.datatype_id`,
 `datapoints`.`value` AS `datapoints.value`,
 `datapoints`.`product_id` AS `datapoints.product_id`,
 `datapoints`.`recorded` AS `datapoints.recorded`,
 `datatypes`.`datatype_id` AS `datatypes.datatype_id`,
 `datatypes`.`datatype_template_id` AS `datatypes.datatype_template_id`,
 `datatypes`.`client_id` AS `datatypes.client_id`,
 `datatypes`.`name` AS `datatypes.name`,
 `datatypes`.`description` AS `datatypes.description`,
 `datatypes`.`options` AS `datatypes.options`,
 `locations`.`location_id` AS `locations.location_id`,
 `locations`.`retailer_group_id` AS `locations.retailer_group_id`,
 `locations`.`latitude` AS `locations.latitude`,
 `locations`.`longitude` AS `locations.longitude`,
 `locations`.`name` AS `locations.name`,
 `locations`.`address` AS `locations.address`,
 `locations`.`city` AS `locations.city`,
 `locations`.`state` AS `locations.state`,
 `locations`.`postal` AS `locations.postal`,
 `locations`.`phone` AS `locations.phone`,
 `locations`.`suburb` AS `locations.suburb`,
 `locations`.`country` AS `locations.country`,
 `locations`.`region` AS `locations.region`,
 `locations`.`coverage` AS `locations.coverage`,
 `locations`.`store_number` AS `locations.store_number`,
 `locations`.`store_type` AS `locations.store_type`

 FROM `fieldreps` AS `fieldreps`

 LEFT JOIN `users` ON (`fieldreps`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`)
 LEFT JOIN `tasks` ON (`fieldreps`.`user_id` = `tasks`.`user_id`)
 LEFT JOIN `datapoints` ON (`tasks`.`task_id` = `datapoints`.`task_id`)
 LEFT JOIN `datatypes` ON (`datapoints`.`datatype_id` = `datatypes`.`datatype_id`)
 LEFT JOIN `locations` ON (`tasks`.`location_id` = `locations`.`location_id`)

 WHERE `fieldreps`.`user_id` LIKE '5f5dc29c-832e-5646-9dc2-46d774bfb1ec'
```

[image: One Result]
[image: Second Result]

[image: No worky]
[image: worked]

I am running the query in phpMyAdmin.  Database is hosted on xeround.com(Could it be a bug in their configuration?)

I am stumped.  I am not sure where to go from here.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Here is the dump from phpMyAdmin:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.3.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Generation Time: Jan 07, 2012 at 08:20 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.42
-- PHP Version: 5.3.1

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `big_development`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `datapoints`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datapoints` (
  `datapoint_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `task_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `datatype_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `product_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `recorded` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  PRIMARY KEY (`datapoint_id`),
  KEY `task_id` (`task_id`),
  KEY `datatype_id` (`datatype_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=Xeround DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `datatypes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datatypes` (
  `datatype_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `datatype_template_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `client_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `options` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  PRIMARY KEY (`datatype_id`),
  KEY `datatype_template_id` (`datatype_template_id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=Xeround DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `fieldreps`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fieldreps` (
  `user_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `availability_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `applicant_type` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `license_number` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `license_exp` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `license_state` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `car` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `authorized_worker` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `restrictions` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `night` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `day` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `longer` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `commitment` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `travel_metro` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `travel_states` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `big_employee` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `employed` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `retail` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `status` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `start` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `sales` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `study` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `relevant` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `experience` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `claims` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `education` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `degree_details` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `degree_institution` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `other_training` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `jobs` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `current_training` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `interested` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `achievements` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `passions` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `ambitions` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `max_travel_time` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `resume` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `availability_id` (`availability_id`)
) ENGINE=Xeround DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `locations`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
  `location_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `retailer_group_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `latitude` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `longitude` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `address` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `city` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `state` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `postal` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `phone` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `suburb` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `country` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `region` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `coverage` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_number` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `store_type` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`),
  KEY `retailer_group_id` (`retailer_group_id`)
) ENGINE=Xeround DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tasks`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (
  `task_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `recurrence_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `location_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `earliest_start` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `deadline` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `km_estimate` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `estimate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
  KEY `campaign_id` (`campaign_id`),
  KEY `location_id` (`location_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `recurrence_id` (`recurrence_id`)
) ENGINE=Xeround DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `given_name` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `nationality` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=Xeround DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

EDIT:

If I remove the join on all tables but user, the query works everytime.  However, as soon as I add the join on tasks, it breaks.  For example, this query breaks it in the same way as the first query I posted:

```
SELECT
`fieldreps`.`user_id` AS `fieldreps.user_id`,
 `fieldreps`.`availability_id` AS `fieldreps.availability_id`,
 `fieldreps`.`applicant_type` AS `fieldreps.applicant_type`,
 `fieldreps`.`license_number` AS `fieldreps.license_number`,
 `fieldreps`.`license_exp` AS `fieldreps.license_exp`,
 `fieldreps`.`license_state` AS `fieldreps.license_state`,
 `fieldreps`.`car` AS `fieldreps.car`,
 `fieldreps`.`authorized_worker` AS `fieldreps.authorized_worker`,
 `fieldreps`.`restrictions` AS `fieldreps.restrictions`,
 `fieldreps`.`night` AS `fieldreps.night`,
 `fieldreps`.`day` AS `fieldreps.day`,
 `fieldreps`.`longer` AS `fieldreps.longer`,
 `fieldreps`.`commitment` AS `fieldreps.commitment`,
 `fieldreps`.`travel_metro` AS `fieldreps.travel_metro`,
 `fieldreps`.`travel_states` AS `fieldreps.travel_states`,
 `fieldreps`.`big_employee` AS `fieldreps.big_employee`,
 `fieldreps`.`employed` AS `fieldreps.employed`,
 `fieldreps`.`retail` AS `fieldreps.retail`,
 `fieldreps`.`status` AS `fieldreps.status`,
 `fieldreps`.`start` AS `fieldreps.start`,
 `fieldreps`.`sales` AS `fieldreps.sales`,
 `fieldreps`.`study` AS `fieldreps.study`,
 `fieldreps`.`relevant` AS `fieldreps.relevant`,
 `fieldreps`.`experience` AS `fieldreps.experience`,
 `fieldreps`.`claims` AS `fieldreps.claims`,
 `fieldreps`.`education` AS `fieldreps.education`,
 `fieldreps`.`degree_details` AS `fieldreps.degree_details`,
 `fieldreps`.`degree_institution` AS `fieldreps.degree_institution`,
 `fieldreps`.`other_training` AS `fieldreps.other_training`,
 `fieldreps`.`jobs` AS `fieldreps.jobs`,
 `fieldreps`.`current_training` AS `fieldreps.current_training`,
 `fieldreps`.`interested` AS `fieldreps.interested`,
 `fieldreps`.`achievements` AS `fieldreps.achievements`,
 `fieldreps`.`passions` AS `fieldreps.passions`,
 `fieldreps`.`ambitions` AS `fieldreps.ambitions`,
 `fieldreps`.`max_travel_time` AS `fieldreps.max_travel_time`,
 `fieldreps`.`creation_time` AS `fieldreps.creation_time`,
 `fieldreps`.`resume` AS `fieldreps.resume`,
 `users`.`user_id` AS `users.user_id`,
     `users`.`email` AS `users.email`,
 `users`.`name` AS `users.name`,
 `users`.`password` AS `users.password`,
 `users`.`given_name` AS `users.given_name`,
 `users`.`title` AS `users.title`,
 `users`.`nationality` AS `users.nationality`,
 `tasks`.`task_id` AS `tasks.task_id`,
 `tasks`.`recurrence_id` AS `tasks.recurrence_id`,
 `tasks`.`parent_id` AS `tasks.parent_id`,
 `tasks`.`user_id` AS `tasks.user_id`,
 `tasks`.`campaign_id` AS `tasks.campaign_id`,
 `tasks`.`location_id` AS `tasks.location_id`,
 `tasks`.`title` AS `tasks.title`,
 `tasks`.`description` AS `tasks.description`,
 `tasks`.`earliest_start` AS `tasks.earliest_start`,
 `tasks`.`deadline` AS `tasks.deadline`,
 `tasks`.`km_estimate` AS `tasks.km_estimate`,
 `tasks`.`estimate` AS `tasks.estimate`

 FROM `fieldreps` AS `fieldreps`

 LEFT JOIN `users` ON (`fieldreps`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`)
 LEFT JOIN `tasks` ON (`fieldreps`.`user_id` = `tasks`.`user_id`)

 WHERE `fieldreps`.`user_id` LIKE '5f5dc29c-832e-5646-9dc2-46d774bfb1ec'
```

Comment: do you have a primary key in all those tables?

Comment: @redmoon7777 Yes I do.  Adding the SQL to the question so you can see.

Comment: have you tried adding an ORDER BY clause just to see what happens?

Comment: @redmoon7777 I just tried ORDER BY `fieldreps`.`user_id` and that did not make a difference.  I also tried LIMIT 0, 100 and that did not make a difference.  What am I missing? :/

Comment: Does the `SELECT * FROM fieldreps WHERE fieldreps.user_id LIKE '5f5dc29c-832e-5646-9dc2-46d774bfb1ec'` always return a row?

Comment: @ypercube Yes it does.  At least, it seems to when I just ran it about 10 times.

Comment: And `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id LIKE '5f5dc29c-832e-5646-9dc2-46d774bfb1ec'`, too?

Comment: @ypercube Yes, just tried it.  I also tried : `SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE user_id LIKE '5f5dc29c-832e-5646-9dc2-46d774bfb1ec'` and it works everytime too.

Comment: Can you try changing `FROM fieldreps AS fieldreps` into: `FROM fieldreps` (without the alias)?

Comment: what happens if you use JOIN without LEFT ? (just trying to figure out where the problem is)

Comment: @redmoon7777 Ok, removed the `WHERE` clause and it still acts irregular.  First run it returns 122 records, second run it returns 20k records. Third run, back to 122 and on and on.

Comment: PS: you use varchar where you should be using int. (just a side note)

Comment: @redmoon7777 Removing `LEFT` did not help.

Comment: could you try only selecting the fieldreps columns:  

SELECT `fieldreps`.* LEFT JOIN ....

Comment: @redmoon7777 Ah, which field are you looking at?  The types probably could be better.  I was using SQLite previously.  SQLite doesn't like types, it's typeless.  So, there could be a bad habit of making all of the field types TEXT.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6512/discussion-between-redmoon7777-and-jonathan)

Comment: @redmoon7777 Changing it to `SELECT
fieldreps.*`  Did not help it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection and database collation differed.